# easy way to make an elasticsearch server read-only

Tags: elasticsearch

It's really easy to just upload a bunch of json data to an elasticsearch server to have a basic query api, with lots of options

I'd just like to know if there's and easy way to publish it all preventing people from modifying it

From the default setting, the server is open ot receive a DELETE or PUT http message that would modify the data.

Is there some kind of setting to configure it to be read-only? Or shall I configure some kind of http proxy to achieve it?

(I'm an elasticsearch newbie)

Answer (score 24):

If you want to expose the  Elasticsearch API as read-only, I think the best way is to put Nginx in front of it, and deny all requests except GET. An example configuration looks like this:

```
# Run me with:
#
#     $ nginx -c path/to/this/file
#
# All requests except GET are denied.

worker_processes  1;
pid               nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  server {

    listen       8080;
    server_name  search.example.com;

    error_log   elasticsearch-errors.log;
    access_log  elasticsearch.log;

    location / {
      if ($request_method !~ "GET") {
        return 403;
        break;
      }

      proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }

  }

}
```

Then:

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/_search -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}}}'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8080/test/test/1 -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/test/
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Note, that a malicious user could still mess up your server, for instance sending incorrect script payloads, which would make Elasticsearch get stuck, but for most purposes, this approach would be fine.

If you would need more control about the proxying, you can either use more complex Nginx configuration, or write a dedicated proxy eg. in Ruby or Node.js.

See this [example](https://gist.github.com/3369662#file-proxy-rb) for a more complex Ruby-based proxy.

Comment: It appears that Kibana will not operate on only "GET" http methods.  Have you encountered a work-around for this?

Comment: Is this still the best solution as of 2020? With security being free recently, maybe there could be better choices now, although this one is definitely the simplest

Answer (score 8):

You can set a readonly flag on your index, this does limit some operations though, so you will need to see if thats acceptable.

```
curl -XPUT http://<ip-address>:9200/<index name>/_settings -d'
{
    "index":{
        "blocks":{
            "read_only":true
        }
    }
}'
```

As mentioned in one of the other answers, really you should have ES running in a trusted environment, where you can control access to it.

More information on index settings here : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old topic. I encountered the same problem, put ES behind Nginx in order to make it read only but allow kibana to access it.

The only request from ES that Kibana needs in my case is "url_public/_all/_search".

So I allowed it into my Nginx conf.

Here my conf file :

```
server {

    listen port_es;
    server_name ip_es;

    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_redirect url_es url_public;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;

    location ~ ^/(_all/_search) {
        limit_except GET POST OPTIONS {
                deny  all;
        }
        proxy_pass url_es;
    }

    location / {

        limit_except GET {
                deny  all;
        }
        proxy_pass url_es;
    }
}
```

So only GET request are allowed unless the request is _all/_search. It is simple to add other request if needed.

Answer (score 6):

I use this elasticsearch plugin:

https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin

It is very simple, easy to install & configure. The GitHub project page has a config example that shows how to limit requests to HTTP GET method only; which will not change any data in elasticsearch. If you need only whitelisted IP#'s (or none) to use other methods (PUT/DELETE/etc) that can change data then it has got you covered as well.

Something like this goes into your elasticsearch config file (/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml or equivalent), adapted from the GitHub page:

```
readonlyrest:
    enable: true
    response_if_req_forbidden: Sorry, your request is forbidden
    # Default policy is to forbid everything, let's define a whitelist
    access_control_rules:

    # from these IP addresses, accept any method, any URI, any HTTP body
    #- name: full access to internal servers
    #  type: allow
    #  hosts: [127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.10]

    # From external hosts, accept only GET and OPTION methods only if the HTTP request body is empty
    - name: restricted access to all other hosts
      type: allow
      methods: [OPTIONS,GET]
      maxBodyLength: 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Elasticsearch is meant to be used in a trusted environment and by itself doesn't have any access control mechanism. So, the best way to deploy elasticsearch is with a web server in front of it that would be responsible for controlling access and type of the queries that can reach elasticsearch. Saying that, it's possible to limit access to elasticsearch by using [elasticsearch-jetty](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty) plugin.

Comment: Using nginx as a password-protected proxy is another simple solution.  The elasticsearch chef cookbook supports this too.

Answer (score 3):

With either Elastic or Solr, it's not a good idea to depend on the search engine for your security. You should be using security in your container, or even putting the container behind something *really* bulletproof like Apache HTTPD, and then setting up the security to forbid the things you want to forbid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public facing ES instance behind nginx, which is updated internally these blocks should make it ready only and only allow _search endpoints

```
    limit_except GET POST OPTIONS {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny  all;
    }
    if ($request_uri !~ .*search.*) {
        set $sc fail;
    }
    if ($remote_addr = 127.0.0.1) {
        set $sc pass;
    }
    if ($sc = fail) {
        return 404;
    }
```