# Start Elasticsearch service with 2 nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to start Elastic search in clustering with 2 nodes :
I run Command :

```
service elasticsearch start
```

then I run 2 instances of elasticsearch in order to join the cluster with commands:

```
/bin/elasticsearch
```

But when I check the head_plugin : `localhost:2900/_plugin/head/` I get the Cluster health status Yellow, and the nodes didn't join the cluster 
How can I configure the two nodes to make them join the cluster ? 
thanks
**EDIT:**
This is what I get :

```
root@vmi17663:~# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true'
{
  "ok" : true,
  "cluster_name" : "nearCluster",
  "nodes" : {
    "aHUjm3SjQa6MbRoWCnL4pQ" : {
      "name" : "Primary node",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/ip@dress:9300]",
      "hostname" : "HOSTNAME",
      "version" : "0.90.5",
      "http_address" : "inet[/ip@dress:9200]"
    }
  }
}root@vmi17663:~# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9201/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true'
{
  "ok" : true,
  "cluster_name" : "nearCluster",
  "nodes" : {
    "pz7dfIABSbKRc92xYCbtgQ" : {
      "name" : "Second Node",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/ip@dress:9301]",
      "hostname" : "HOSTNAME",
      "version" : "0.90.5",
      "http_address" : "inet[/ip@dress:9201]"
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do the logs say? what means of [cluster discovery](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html) did you configure for your system?

Comment: I updated Elastic search to the last version, I'll see what this gives

Comment: I think it's a firewall matter as the discovery uses the port 54328 and my iptables is closing that port! 
I'll try updating my iptables and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: try using the more explicit unicast discovery methods, please read the doco.

Comment: Ok! I tried to open the port 54328 with Iptables when I test it it's always closed.
It's listed as accepted in my 
iptables --list command though

Comment: I added this rule 
-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
and it worked !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work ! 
As expected It was iptables Problem I added this rule

```
-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

and everything went smooth

Comment: How should this be modified to allow it from localhost only? Is this entry allowing multicast packets coming from outside the box?

Comment: You mean protecting your Elasticsearch server from outside curls ? 
If that's the case you need further rules look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14115520/3062150

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have different `elasticsearch.yml` files for each node.
Make sure each is configured to join the same cluser via `cluster.name: "mycluster"`

You can start an additional nodes (new jvm process) off the same code install like this:

`<es home>/bin/elasticsearch -d -Des.config=<wherever>/elasticsearch-1/config/elasticsearch.yml`

`<es home>/bin/elasticsearch -d -Des.config=<wherever>/elasticsearch-2/config/elasticsearch.yml`

My setup looks like this:

```
elasticsearch-1.0.0.RC1
├── LICENSE.txt
├── NOTICE.txt
├── README.textile
├── bin
├── config
├── data
├── lib
├── logs
└── plugins
elasticsearch-2
├── config
├── data
├── logs
├── run
└── work
elasticsearch-3
├── config
├── data
├── logs
├── run
└── work
elasticsearch-1
├── config
├── data
├── logs
├── run
└── work
```

I start all three with aliases like this:

```
alias startes1='/usr/local/elasticsearch-1.0.0.RC1/bin/elasticsearch -d -Des.config=/usr/local/elasticsearch-1/config/elasticsearch.yml'
alias startes2='/usr/local/elasticsearch-1.0.0.RC1/bin/elasticsearch -d -Des.config=/usr/local/elasticsearch-2/config/elasticsearch.yml'
alias startes3='/usr/local/elasticsearch-1.0.0.RC1/bin/elasticsearch -d -Des.config=/usr/local/elasticsearch-3/config/elasticsearch.yml'
```

Comment: I ignore why it refuses to work the second node is always elected as master even if I put .master = false ! <br>
is it because I start the main node as service ?

Comment: I would not start any nodes as service. I prefer to be explicit about what config to use in the command itself

Comment: the service starts with the default config file That I can manipulate 
I also tried running both instances manually , but still the cluster contains only 1 node ..

Answer (score 1):

If your nodes don't join, then you need to check your cluster.name setting, and make sure that each node can communicate to each other via port 9300. (9200 is for incoming traffic, and 9300 is for node to node traffic).

So as @mcolin mentioned make sure your cluster name is the same for each node. To do so, open up your /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml file on your 1st server, and find the line that says "cluster.name" and note what it is set to. Then go to your other servers and make sure they are set to the exact same thing.

To do this, you could run this command:
`sudo vim /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

and set the following line to be something like:
`cluster.name: my_node_name`

Additionally, your nodes might not be able to talk to each other. My nodes are running on AWS, so I went to my EC2 panel and made sure my instances were in the same security group. Then I set my security group to allow all instances within it to talk to each other by creating a rule like this:

`Custom TCP Rule   TCP   9300  dev-elasticsearch`

(or to be wild and dangerous, set this:)

`All traffic       All   All   dev-elasticsearch`

Within a minute of setting this I checked my cluster status and all was well:

`curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'`